# nvim for python, ipython

Tags: python, ipython, neovim

I am learning python and new to nvim.
Using iterm2 is there way to send lines of code to the second tab for run with opened ipython?
As far as I know there is a plugin vim-slime but I am not sure if it is the solution to my question. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do this directly.
https://coderwall.com/p/k-in2g/vim-slime-iterm2

If you run into any problems you could always run screen||tmux in iterm2 and pipe to those. Python's indentation has a slight complication in passing to the REPL. However, the git repo for vim-slime has directions on what to add to your vimrc to make this work seemlessly.